# Is it possible for client control to listen to server events without polling

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have an asp.net text box:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="myTxtBox"/>
```

I need to update this text box everytime a field in the database changes.(price field)
The price field in the databse changes every second.
I know that I can poll every second but I dont want to do this.
One option is to use event mecahnism(but not sure how to achieve it through that)
Is there a better solution?

Comment: you need to take a look on websocket with [signalr](http://signalr.net/)

Comment: Depending on your version of .net you can use signalR, it uses websockets, and if they're not available then a few other techniques, then polling as its last option

Comment: .net 4.0...but can you give a few datils on how to design this?

Comment: We can't possibly teach you signalR in comments, Cuong gave you a website that you can use. You can also use asp.net/signalr. They have some video tutorials and text tutorials

Comment: soory...missed that out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depends on your context. There is list of technicals you can choose:

1. Using signalR (here is the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) link). It is very easy.
2. Build by yourself [COMET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891053.aspx) apply .Net technical

Comment: I think this is what I need .http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr